# Don't focus div with tabindex when user clicked element

Tags: html, focus, accessibility, tabindex

I added `tabindex="0"` to add the ability for users to tab to this `div` and use the keyboard to interact with it. Upon click or hitting enter/space when it's active, a popup `div` is presented. The focus style it applies to the `div` upon hitting tab is fine, but I noticed when users click on the `div` to activate it, the focus style is applied to it at that time as well. If they hold the mouse down the focus style is applied to it.

How can I only provide a visual focus for this `div` when the user tabbed to it, but don't show the focus when the user clicked on it?

I am currently removing focus via `.blur()` when it's activated but there is still a flash of this focus style and it's always visible while the user is holding the mouse down.

A similar interface that exhibits the desired behavior is the Pages app on iCloud.com. You can tab to focus the different icons in the toolbar, then when you tab to your name and hit return/space, a popup appears and the focus on your name is removed. At that point the name text color changes to a darker gray. If you clicked on your name instead of using the keyboard, you never see the focus that is applied to your name, you only see the text color change when the popup is presented.

Comment: Apple is doing that focus with a class of "focus" that changes the background image. The :focus style is "outline 0", which means that they are suppressing the browser's outline style and not replacing it. This is definitely an alternative, but it does not "fix" your issue, it circumvents the behavior because the behavior is expected and cannot be "fixed".

Comment: Thanks @unobf, I've decided to override the default focus style with an acceptable style for everyone to see, then I manually blur it when the user clicks to dismiss the popup to remove the focus style. But I don't do that if they dismiss via keyboard shortcut (different event listeners). Care to update your answer to note this 'workaround' that can be done?

Comment: when you say that it is a different handler, what do you mean? If you read the blog post I put in a comment below http://unobfuscated.blogspot.com/2013/05/event-handlers-and-screen-readers.html then you will see that it is very difficult to tell the difference between a screen reader user and a mouse user. Some screen reader users use a screen reader with a screen magnifier (i.e. they are able to use sight for some things and augment that with the voice from the screen reader) you might be introducing issues for these users.

Comment: I have an onclick handler and an onkeydown handler and they do different things as desired.

Comment: In IE, the screen reader will only send a "click" event and no keyboard events. In addition, by pressing the correct keyboard combination, a screen reader user can simulate a mouse click (VO-SPACE with VoiceOver). This "fix" is not good practice.

Comment: @unobf I've tested it with the mouse, keyboard, and VoiceOver and it works beautifully as desired for all three.

Comment: When you press CTRL-OPTION-SPACE on the modal dismiss with VO, does the browser have an outline in addition to the VO outline? Also, did you test on Windows with IE and NVDA/JAWS?

Comment: @unobf If you hit esc to dismiss the popup when you're on the original button then focus is preserved on the button that presented the popup both with VoiceOver and the CSS focus style. Is that the question you're asking? If you navigate through the list then hit esc neither VO nor the style is displayed despite the fact the button is still selected, not sure why it doesn't move the focus. If you navigate back up to the button when the popup is presented (I support that) then hit VO-space it dismisses the popup and the VO focus is preserved but not the CSS focus style.

Comment: Is there a close button in the dialog itself?

Comment: @unobf it's not a dialog but rather more of a popup menu, there is not a close button

Answer (score 1):

For focusable elements, you should always use `tabindex="0"` (See ["Keyboard Navigation Between Components (The Tab Sequence)"](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#kbd_general_between)) so that the focus happens in the correct DOM order - otherwise the tabindex itself can lead to additional usability/accessibility problems.

If you want it to be focusable, then you definitely want the focus outline to appear when the user clicks it too because click events can be triggered by assistive technology that acts like a keyboard and you want sighted users to be able to see where they are at all times.

One solution is to use `outline: 0` for the `:focus` and `:active` pseudo-classes and then use your own background images to present the different looks you want.

A second solution, which should only be used in the case of a popup that does not have a visible close button, but is dismissed by clicking outside of the popup or by pressing a keyboard command, is to detect the use of the mouse and then blur the element so as to remove the focus outline.

Comment: In this case clicking/activating this element presents a different element, therefore once it has been clicked/activated I don't want the focus to be visible. It only needs to show the focus around the element when users tab to it, not if they click it, otherwise the UI looks very odd for traditional mouse users.

Comment: If you present a different element when clicking this, then in order to be accessible, your focus should move to the newly visible element or a blind user would not be aware that the content has appeared.

Comment: Right, that's easy enough to do. But how do I prevent the focus from appearing for those who just click on the element as opposed to those who manually focused it with the tab key?

Comment: Only way to try would be to try to detect a mouse and reset the focus, the problem with that is it is difficult to do reliably, if not impossible, and not mess it up for one of the keyboard only users unobfuscated.blogspot.com/2013/05/event-handlers-and-screen-readers.html. However, if the mouse user clicks on the element, the focus will move to the newly appeared element, then the other focus outline will disappear, so it becomes a moot point.

Comment: I've added more info to the question to provide an example of what I am attempting to accomplish from another website I use. I never want the focus to appear for those who click on the element. It's definitely possible (see provided website), and I would imagine you don't need to resort to a hack like detecting mouse movement to reset focusses.

Answer (score 0):

A custom control, such as a custom element button, can use :focus-visible to selectively apply a focus indicator only on keyboard-focus.

:focus-visible is what you are looking for

Comment: It be good to add code or a detailed explanation to the code. Happy Contributing :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `focus-visible` css selector to apply different styles for keyboard focus and mouse click.

The way I implemented it is like this:

```
.your-element's-classname:focus:not(:focus-visible) {  outline: none; }
```

When you focus it with the keyboard you will see the browser's focus styling or the custom styling you have made for your element, and when you click it you will see no styling because I have applied `outline:none` which removes the outline created by the browser's focus styling.

You can find more information in [Mozilla's `focus-visible` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) and [Chromium's browser focus article](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/09/giving-users-and-developers-more.html#:%7E:text=Highlight%20come%20in.-,%3Afocus%2Dvisible,with%20a%20mouse%20does%20not.).